# changing a value to next value in an array

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a routine to calculate the proper futures contract front month
If i have a array of integers denoting month numbers ie, "1,4,7,10,12"
and I have a variable integer that is 2.

How do i test the variable against the array and change the variable to the next highest available in the array if the variable itself wasn't in the array? ie in this case the variable's value of 2 would become 4.

I've tried various ways but am stuck now

```
If datenum >= (targetdayofmonth + adjdays) Then
        currentmonth = currentmonth + 1
        Dim currmonthname As String = MonthName(currentmonth, True)
        For x As Integer = 0 To contractmonths.Count - 1
            If GetMonthNumberfromShortMonthName(contractmonths(x)) = currentmonth Then
                currmonthname = currmonthname
            Else

            End If
        Next
    Else
        Dim currmonthname As String = MonthName(currentmonth, True)
    End If
```

So based on Tim's comments I've updated the code to;

```
 Dim contractmonthNos As New List(Of Int32)
    For Each childnode As XmlNode In From childnode1 As XmlNode In root Where childnode1.SelectSingleNode("futures/symbol/Code").InnerText = commodcode
        'get the available contract months for this contract
        Dim contractmonthnodes As XmlNode = childnode.SelectSingleNode("ContractMonths")
        contractmonthNos.AddRange(From subnode As XmlNode In contractmonthnodes Select GetMonthNumberfromShortMonthName(subnode.Name))
    Next
If datenum >= (targetdayofmonth + adjdays) Then
        currentmonth = currentmonth + 1
        Dim currmonthname As String = MonthName(currentmonth, True)
    Else
        Dim nextmonth = From month As Integer In contractmonthNos Where month >   currentmonth
        If nextmonth.Any() Then
            currentmonth = nextmonth.First()
        End If
        Dim currmonthname As String = MonthName(currentmonth, True)
    End If
```

but I am getting a VS2012 squiggly under nextmonth in the If Then Else warning of "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Dim intVar = 2
Dim months = { 1,4,7,10,12 }
Dim higherMonths = months.Where(Function(month) month > intVar).ToArray()
If higherMonths.Any() Then
    intVar = higherMonths.First()
End If
```

If you don't want the next available month in the array but the nearest you have to sort before:

```
Dim higherMonths = months.Where(Function(m) m> intVar).
                          OrderBy(Function(m) m).
                          ToArray()
If higherMonths.Any() Then
    intVar = higherMonths.First()
End If
```

Comment: How do I create this Dim months = { 1,4,7,10,12 } from a for each loop? I am getting the array of integers from an xml file and am getting them as a string and converting them to an array of integers like so Dim contractmonths() as integer = GetMonthNumberfromShortMonthName(subnode.Name) ("subnode.Name is the short month name)

Comment: Then i would use a `List(Of Int312)` instead of an array. If you insist on an array you could use `list.ToArray()` at the end.

Comment: @dinotom: Edited my answer. Materialize the query with `ToList`or `ToArray`. I've used method syntax now, if you want to use Linq's query syntax as before you need to surround the query with paranthesis before you can add `ToArray`.

Comment: i have fixed per your suggestions and it works thank you, and I plus one'd you

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' N.B. this needs to the array to be sorted.
        Dim a() As Integer = {1, 4, 7, 10, 12}
        Dim toFind As Integer = 2
        Dim foundAt As Integer = -1
        For i = 0 To a.Length() - 1
            If a(i) >= toFind Then
                foundAt = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If foundAt >= 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Looked for {0}, found {1}.", toFind, a(foundAt)))
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Did not find {0} or higher.", toFind))
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Or you might want to look at using the [Array.BinarySearch Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx).